# How to get the Artifact id for existing project in POM.XML in maven

Tags: xml, maven, pom.xml, artifact

I unfortunately removed the artificate id. So, can anyone tell me to to retain that in Maven?

```
  <artifactId>  </artifactId>
```

Comment: You have to provide more details. Telling us that some string was lost from pom will not help recover it.... Is your file version controlled? Do you build and upload the artifact to a maven repository?

Comment: What about your version control?

Answer (score 0):

The `groupId` for an artifact is generally the some prefix of the top level package of the code in a module. The `artifactId` is a string that is useful for distinguishing between artifacts that are in the same groupID, and often has a name like "core" or "web", for instance. The name is completely arbitrary.